# Key Listener doesn't detect spacebar

Tags: java

I have JTextPane and added key listener to it. Code looks like:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    JTextPane codePane = new JTextPane(); 

    MainPanel() {
        add(new JScrollPane(codePane));
        codePane.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());
    }

    private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ev) {
            if (ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                System.out.println("space");
            } else {
                System.out.println("char");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I type "sp " i get 3 times: char. It doesn't even detect pressing SPACEBAR. How to solve it?

Comment: "keyTyped(KeyEvent k) - this event occurs after the user types a key that can be represented as a Unicode character. This means you can only use this event when concerned with letters, numbers and symbols. Keys such as page-up, shift, and function keys don't generate a keyTyped() event. keyTyped() does not concern itself with keyboard layout, so it's your best choice when working on programs that will run on multiple platforms."

Comment: Read the API for the `getKeyCode()` method to understand what value is returned when this method is invoked.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* check against `KeyEvent#getKeyChar`, but....

`KeyListeners` have a major limitation when interacting with `KeyEvents` from Swing components, in that they require focus from the component. Never use these. [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) do not require focus and can be used to map `KeyStrokes`.

Having said that, the preferred approach for `JTextComponents`, such as this `JTextPane` would be to use a `DocumentListener`.

See: [DocumentListener Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding `keyTyped()` method, override `keyReleased()` or `keyPressed()` methods. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if (Character.isSpaceChar(ev.getKeyChar()) {
            System.out.println("space");
        }
```

it works for me